# What are the supported databases in yii framework?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

1. What are the **"supported databases"** in yii framework?
2. What is best extension for **"mongo db"** in yii ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your 2nd question

In my openion it's  yiimongodbsuite. It's Full-featured ActiveRecord like support for MongoDB in Yii.

[yiimongodbsuite Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/)

Answer (score 7):

Answer to your 1st question

```
SQLite: sqlite:/path/to/dbfile
MySQL: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb
PostgreSQL: pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=testdb
SQL Server: mssql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb
Oracle: oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/testdb
```